# jquery, update text box after trigger not working

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#cornercases').val('10')                
$('#cornercases').trigger('change',function () 
                {
                    alert("HELLO WORLD");
                    $('input[name="temp_2"]').val('555');                
                });
```

I set a value of 10 to create 10 textboxes on the fly. After the change, I like to update the values in the created textbox. How come the code within the function isn't work?

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Please add the jQuery version, maybe there's some problems with it (i know that i was bitten by advices on the web that didn't warn me about the version they used)

Comment: Cna you show us your full code?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  `trigger` != `bind`

Comment: Where are you attaching event "change"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to `bind` an event handler, not `trigger` the event.

[`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) doesn't actually take a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to bind to change event. Try this

```
$('#cornercases').val('10')                
$('#cornercases').bind('change',function () 
                {
                    alert("HELLO WORLD");
                    $('input[name="temp_2"]').val('555');                
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the function change like this :

```
$('#cornercases').bind('change', function() {
   alert("HELLO WORLD");
   $('input[name="temp_2"]').val('555');  
});
```

Then Trigger the change event where you want....

```
$('#cornercases').trigger('change');
```